# Add listener to span content change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a short snippet of code that I'd like to be run every time a dropdown, made from a `ul`(for CSS purposes), changes its value.

```
<span class="persons">5 personer</span>
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">5 personer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6 personer</a></li>
    <li class="goodprice"><a href="#">7 personer (mer prisvärt)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">8 personer</a></li>
    <li class="goodprice"><a href="#">9 personer (mer prisvärt)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">10 personer</a></li>
    <li class="goodprice"><a href="#">11 personer (mer prisvärt)</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
var persons = $('.persons').text();

if (persons == "5 personer" || persons == "6 personer" || persons == "7 personer (mer prisvärt)") {
    $('#boattype1').show();
    $('#boattype2').show();
    $('#boattype3').hide();
} else if (persons == "8 personer" || persons == "9 personer (mer prisvärt)") {
    $('#boattype1').show();
    $('#boattype2').hide();
    $('#boattype3').show();
}
```

So what I need is the JS code to be triggered once you select something new from the `ul`. I've tried to add things like `$('ul a').click(function() {});` and `$('span').change(function() {});` without any results, so I'm in big need of your help to solve this, hopefully, small problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a span does not have a `change` event natively, but there is nothing stopping you manually triggering it, and then any subscription to that event will fire:

```
$(function(){
    $('.persons').change(function() {
       console.log('span changed to ' + $(this).text());
    });

    $('ul li a').click(function(){
        $('.persons').text($(this).text()).trigger('change');
    });
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/djB83/

Comment: That's a good start, but I didn't get it to work in combination with my code. The first trigger fires away, but not the next-coming ones. And whatever I click on, it will only hide and show the items as selected on row 6-9 in the JS code.

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/djB83/1/

Comment: You had the code which reads the text outside of the `change` handler so it was only ever read once (on load) not every time the span changes. See update: http://jsfiddle.net/djB83/2/